# He closed the door CAREFULLY or He CAREFULLY closed the door

Tags: grammar, adverb-placement

Which is considered as grammatical and better?

> He closed the door **carefully**

Or

> He **carefully** closed the door

This is about the adverb of manner (**carefully**), *grammar rules* indicate that the *adverb of manner* should be **after** the main verb (**close**).

But can I also say it the other way particularly using sentence  #2? (I can't ask this in a grammar book of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find this passage useful from [this site](http://www.wordpower.ws/grammar/gramch24.html).

> Adverbs of manner most often occupy the end position of a clause, where they follow an intransitive verb, or the direct object of a transitive verb.
>   e.g. **We waited patiently for the play to begin**.
>         **I sold the strawberries quickly**.
>   In the first example, the adverb of manner patiently follows the intransitive verb waited. In the second example, the adverb of manner quickly follows the direct object strawberries of the transitive verb sold.
>
> An adverb of manner may be placed at the beginning of a clause, in
>   order to emphasize the idea expressed by the adverb. e.g. Patiently,
>   we waited for the show to begin.
>         Quickly, I sold the strawberries. In these examples, the ideas expressed by patiently and quickly are emphasized.
>
> Adverbs of manner are often placed in the middle position of a clause,
>   particularly when the clause contains no adverb of frequency. e.g. **I
>   slowly opened the door**.
>         **I have carefully considered all of the possibilities**. In the first example, the adverb of manner slowly precedes opened, a verb in
>   the Simple Past. In the second example, the adverb of manner carefully
>   follows the auxiliary have of the verb have considered.

Comment: Thx a bunch. So that's the reason why I see adverb of manner placed like that.